# Strong operator and ultrastrong topologies are the same on bounded subsets

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In class, we proved that weak operator and ultraweak topologies coincide on norm-bounded subsets of $\mathcal{B} (\mathcal{H})$ (here, $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space) using Banach-Alaoglu. This had me wondering whether the same is also true for strong operator and ultrastrong topologies. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrastrong_topology) claims it is, but doesn't give a reference. Does there exist an elementary proof of this?

Comment: Yes - the seminorms generating the strong operator topology are dense in all seminorms generating the ultrastrong topology, so you can use a $3\epsilon$-style approximation argument for this.

Comment: Alternatively just apply the result with weak and ultraweak topologies - $a_\lambda \to a$ strongly (or ultrastrongly) iff $|a_\lambda - a|^2 \to 0$ weakly (or ultraweakly, respectively).

Comment: @DavidGao Oh I see, thanks (again) for your reply!